# Laravel eloquent many to many and has many relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this `Warehouse → many to many → Product → has many → Sale`

My relationships

warehouse.php

```
public function products () {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot('quantity');
}
```

product.php

```
public function sales () {
    return $this->hasMany(Sale::class);
}
```

I want to get sales for each warehouse

What I have tried

```
return Warehouse::with('products.sales')->get();
```

Unexpected restult

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "warehouse": "India",
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 19,
            "name": "Taylor Lester",
            "price": "745.00",
            "sales": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "warehouse_id": 1,
                    "product_id": 19,
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "quantity": 20
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "warehouse_id": 1,
                    "product_id": 19,
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "quantity": 30
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "warehouse": "Malaysia",
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 19,
            "name": "Taylor Lester",
            "price": "745.00",
            "sales": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "warehouse_id": 1,
                    "product_id": 19,
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "quantity": 20
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "warehouse_id": 1,
                    "product_id": 19,
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "quantity": 30
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want is for each warehouse get the sales. Like Indian warehouse has only 2 sales but Malaysian warehouse has only 1 sale

How can I implement this approach?

Comment: You have a `warehouse_id` on your sales. That may result in update anomalies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the data, your `Sale` model has a `warehouse_id` column. Why is that relationship not on your `Warehouse` model already?

```php
class Warehouse extends Model
{
    public function sales () {
        return $this->hasMany(Sale::class);
    }
}
```

And then

```php
return Warehouse::with('sales')->get();
```

Comment: I've already did it and it worked. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

use [withCount](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) in laravel to only count related models

```
return Warehouse::with('products' => function($query){
    $query->withCount('sales');
})->get();
```